# React App on Azure Webapp Service via Github fails with MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: reactjs, azure, web-applications, modulenotfounderror

I have a react app which is running perfectly fine on prem.

I created Azure Web App and configured GitHub repo which has the react js code. The build and deployment went fine thought it takes close to 2 hours.

After the deployment, I notice that it fails with MODULE_NOT_FOUND error.

I tried both the versions below under the scripts section of the package.json

1. "start": "react-scripts start",
2. "start": "/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",

Error Logs:

```
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717089653Z    _____                               
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717127133Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717136631Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717140979Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717145377Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717149796Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717153343Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717156809Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717160115Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717161989Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717163812Z NodeJS Version : v18.16.1
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717165585Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2023-08-26T21:22:06.717167419Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:07.244829379Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2023-08-26T21:22:07.394588279Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2023-08-26T21:22:07.609497822Z Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2023-08-26T21:22:07.609529071Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2023-08-26T21:22:07.609535893Z Build Operation ID: f88a9047-884b-4267-95d9-2085b8a5e06d
2023-08-26T21:22:07.828483725Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..
2023-08-26T21:22:07.867662678Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928152795Z Running #!/bin/sh
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928182200Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928189413Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928216364Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928221193Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928225651Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928230240Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928234648Z      export PORT=8080
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928238776Z fi
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928242313Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:07.928245759Z npm start
2023-08-26T21:22:15.473095058Z npm info using npm@9.6.4
2023-08-26T21:22:15.476135731Z npm info using node@v18.16.1
2023-08-26T21:22:15.769149040Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:15.769177904Z > poll-ui@0.1.0 start
2023-08-26T21:22:15.769185007Z > react-scripts start
2023-08-26T21:22:15.769190357Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:15.996996292Z node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997126006Z   throw err;
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997133580Z   ^
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997149409Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997153848Z Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997157745Z Require stack:
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997161462Z - /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997165089Z     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997168856Z     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:116:19)
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997172342Z     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:31:23)
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997176330Z     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997179646Z     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997183453Z     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997187000Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997190606Z     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997193993Z     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997197509Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997201337Z   requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts' ]
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997205474Z }
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997768208Z 
2023-08-26T21:22:15.997777886Z Node.js v18.16.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have built (using a command like `yarn build`) and deployed the app in azure app service on linux mode.

all you need to do now is add the following script as the Startup Command in your Azure web apps Configuration -> General Settings tab :  `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon`

example :
[image]

Check this for the documentation by Azure : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am using npm run build. I added your start up command and I still ge the same issue.

Comment: What are you deploying to app service? The build artifact or your source code?

Comment: Yes I am deploying to azure app service. I deployed it using the source code repo from GitHub